# How to customize hover information depending on variable value

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe with several columns. I'm interested in displaying some of this info when hovering over a specific point using plotly with python. I've discovered how to do this using `customdata=dataframme[["A","B"]]` being provided to my `go.scatter`.
Problem is that when I create `hovertemplate`, it could happen I don't want to display some info it that value is not available.
This is the code snippet :

```
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=df['Request time'], y=df['Taken time'], name="System performance", hovertemplate=
        "<br>Request period: %{text}<br>" +
        "Taken time: %{y}<br>" +
        "Error msg: %{customdata[0]}<br>" +
        "LogCorr: %{customdata[1]}<br>",
                   customdata=df[["ai","logCorr"]],
                   text=df['Request period']),
        secondary_y=True,
    )
```

This is working fine, but if I leave this like it is, when "ai" value is empty, I see quite ugly hover

[image]

I was thinking if there is some way to display hover info when column value exists (in my case) and display nothing when it doesn't
Something so "easy" like `"" if X==0 else "Error message : %{customdata[1]}` in hovertemplate.
This is not working due to customdata means nothing to python in execution time. I've tried for looking which language is used in hovertemplate but no luck

Thanks a lot for your help

Sure, @Phoenix, Thanks for your help

```
Result,Request period,Request time,Taken time,rc,ac,ai,logCorr,rcvTS,to
0,2022.09.21D15:50:06-2022.09.21D15:51:06,2022-09-21 15:54:28.620446,0:00:00.392736,0,0,,2f85cfdd-9539-49d7-83af-8df98619dd52,2022-09-21 15:54:28.939000,2022-09-21 15:54:58.939000
0,2022.09.21D15:51:10-2022.09.21D15:52:10,2022-09-21 15:54:29.367677,0:00:00.367510,0,0,,18e61236-3b70-46e9-8b0d-c1bdc7557ed8,2022-09-21 15:54:29.662000,2022-09-21 15:54:59.662000
0,2022.09.21D15:52:19-2022.09.21D15:53:19,2022-09-21 15:54:30.085704,0:00:00.357543,0,0,,7c3784fb-481b-432b-80d9-4c1654bcb565,2022-09-21 15:54:30.383000,2022-09-21 15:55:00.383000
0,2022.09.21D15:53:26-2022.09.21D15:54:26,2022-09-21 15:54:30.792658,0:00:00.375392,0,0,Time out,b52126a5-7c1b-4898-811d-65446fdda65d,2022-09-21 15:54:31.092000,2022-09-21 15:55:01.092000
```

In this example latest line contains timeout error and rest of lines do not contain any error. When I try to run this, `Time out` is properly displayed, problem is that when there is no `ai`, I see what you see in my screen shot.

When a column in csv does not have info, pandas is reading it as `nan`

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this cannot be done for the moment. [link](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3515)

Comment: Please, provide us with some samples of dummy data and I think I can solve this problem.

Comment: @Phoenix I've edited provided info to give more details. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by when there is no ai? Nan in the cell of the dataframe?

Comment: `,,`  in the csv file. Not sure how that is mapped by panda by default

Comment: But you need first to read it into pandas dataframe to be able to plot by plotly.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to say that I didn't know how panda was reading that "no info" intro dataframe. I've checked and it's `nan`

Comment: I solved similar question here, please take  a look and see how you can solve your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73866051/16733101

Comment: Thanks for your workaround @Hamzah, I would have prefer manage it using hover itself, but it's better than having an ugly "template" being displayed. I think I'm going to modify how I create csv file, I'm creating it so I can set a default value before.